# Create new column by manipulating existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have many columns in  dataframe , I want to fill one column by manipulating other two column in same datframe

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
nan     1      2      4
2       2      2      3
3       nan    1      2
```

I want fill value of col1 ,col2 and col3 if nan exist on the basis of col1 ,col2 and col3 value.

I have code as follows:

```
indices_of_nan_cell = [(index,col1,col2,col3) for index,(col1,col2,col3) in enumerate(zip(col1,col2,col3)) if str(col1)=='nan' or str(col2)=='nan' or str(col3)=='nan']


for nan_values in indices:
    if np.isnan(nan_values[1]) or nan_values[1] == 'nan':
       read4['col1'][nan_values[0]]=float(nan_values[2])*float(nan_values[3])
    if np.isnan(nan_values[2]) or nan_values[2] == 'nan':
       read4['col2'][nan_values[0]]=float(nan_values[1])/float(nan_values[3])
    if np.isnan(nan_values[3]) or nan_values[3] == 'nan':
       read4['col3'][nan_values[0]]=float(nan_values[1])*float(nan_values[2])
```

It's working fine for me , but taking to much time as I have rows in thousands in my dataframe, Is there any efficient way,we can do this?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: are you talking about using the .fillna() function from pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace `NaN`s only with [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html), [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) and parameter `fill_value` for replace `NaN`s in division and multiplication:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna(df['col2'].mul(df['col3'], fill_value=1))
df['col2'] = df['col2'].fillna(df['col1'].div(df['col3'], fill_value=1))
df['col3'] = df['col3'].fillna(df['col1'].mul(df['col2'], fill_value=1))

print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   2.0   1.0     2     4
1   2.0   2.0     2     3
2   3.0   3.0     1     2
```

Another approach is working only with `NaN`s rows:

```
m1 = df['col1'].isna()
m2 = df['col2'].isna()
m3 = df['col3'].isna()
#oldier versions of pandas
#m1 = df['col1'].isnull()
#m2 = df['col2'].isnull()
#m3 = df['col3'].isnull()

df.loc[m1, 'col1'] = df.loc[m1, 'col2'].mul(df.loc[m1, 'col3'], fill_value=1)
df.loc[m2, 'col2'] = df.loc[m2, 'col1'].div(df.loc[m2, 'col3'], fill_value=1)
df.loc[m3, 'col3'] = df.loc[m3, 'col1'].mul(df.loc[m3, 'col2'], fill_value=1)
```

**Explanation**:

1. Filter each column with [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html) for 3 separate boolean masks.
2. For each mask first filter rows like `df.loc[m1, 'col2']` and multiple or divide
3. Last assign back - replace `NaN`s only because filtering again by `df.loc[m1, 'col1']`

Comment: it check for only nan values or goes through all the rows of particulate column?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - It count all values.

Comment: because I want if col1 cell value is not nan then should not happen any manipulation.It should be as it is. like this should happen for all columns.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - Ya, understand. Then use second solution.

Comment: bro can you please explain another approch?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - sure, give me some time.